# Example of two series with $a_n \leq b_n$ for $n \geq n_0$ but still $\sum_{n \geq 0} a_n>\sum_{n \geq 0} b_n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

Can anyone suggest an example of two real number series $\sum_{n \geq 0} a_n$ and $\sum_{n \geq 0} b_n$ such that the following conditions hold?

- $ a_n \geq 0$ and $  b_n\geq0 $$\,\,\,\,\,\,\forall n \geq
     0$
- $ a_n \leq b_n\,\,\,\,\,\,\forall n \geq n_0 >0$
- $\sum_{n \geq 0} a_n>\sum_{n \geq 0} b_n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just take any example where $a_n=b_n$ for all $n\geq n_0$ but $a_n>b_n$ for all $n<n_0$ (and the sums converge).

More generally, the point is that you're completely free to choose $a_0,\dots,a_{n_0-1}$.  So for instance, given any convergent series of nonnegative numbers $b_n$, you could pick $a_0>\sum_{n\geq 0} b_n$ and just set $a_n=0$ for all $n>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Choose $a_n$ such that first $n_0$ terms sum to something larger than the sum of all $b_n$. Really just take any $b_n$ whose sum converges and consider the sequence $a_0=1, a_i=b_{i-1}$ for $i > 1$. Then true for $n_0=1$.

Comment: Your first example is fine, but your second example usually won't satisfy $a_n\leq b_n$ for $n\geq n_0$.

Comment: You are correct, thanks!